# how to effectively manage input dataset for lightgbm to avoid memory error

Tags: out-of-memory, sparse-matrix, lightgbm

I am trying to fit a lightgbm model multiclass model on large dataframe:

```
train_data = lgb.Dataset(train_df[v1].values, label=label)
```

`631,761 x 1786` columns (2.2gb). This runs fine. However, there is one column, which has 10000 unique classes (which I am currently using in model with the help of `pd.factorize`). However I want to transpose them and use as indicators for each class as below:

```
train_data = lgbm.Dataset(train_df[v1].values, label=label,feature_name=v1,categorical_feature=['ward_id'])
```

This transformation is leading to memory error. Is there any efficient way to do it, without running into memory error.

here are my configurations:

```
Core i7, 16 GB ram.
```

Comment: what kind of transformation do you mean? What you described triggers a dedicated categorical treatment inside lightgbm, but I'm not sure it is a transform per se (rather a special way how to evaluate splits). a side question, are you sure you need to keep all 10k classes? Maybe you can cut all below a certain threshold in rate?

Comment: that's a good idea. but even after choosing threshold, i still have 6k classes. transformation, i mean one hot encoding

Comment: Light gem internally does *not* do ohe. It has a different treatment implemented. What exactly do you do in the second option? Do you do ‘pd.get_dummies’ yourself?

Comment: yea. I do pd.get_dummies. it seems, lightgbm somehow works after reducing categories and putting as categorical feature than dummies

Comment: One clarification: it is  *NOT* a must to do OHE with LightGBM. One *CAN* do it, but there is an alternative: label-encode your categorical features and point at that column as a `categorical_feature` to trigger internal handling. If your inputs are in `pd.DataFrame`, then you even do not have to do that- you can simply set `dtype` of the relevant column to `'category'` and this will by default trigger label-encoding followed by special internal treatment. OHE for trees are difficult, because one might need MANY splits for the single feature, if there are many classes + memory is an issue